# fs.writeFile how to disable escaping at stuff like \n

Tags: node.js, escaping, electron, fs

I have a website with node.js enabled.

User will enter a key via form and then in the script we will get a string like this. The user will enter \n because it´s copy and paste from a private Key

so as example:

```
hello how are you\nvery good :)
```

HTML looks like this

```
  <form id="FORM_Key">
      <button id="send_Key">Save</button>
       <label for="Textarea_Key">
        <input type="text" id="Textarea_Key" class="dropdown_textarea" name="Textarea_Key" placeholder="Enter Private Key.." onclick="addHandler_Key();">
       </label>
    </form>
```

Then I make a console.log of this string that will be generated by the input and it´s the same output like above. @Crogo commented below that it´s already been escaped because I saw \n in this log! In other words this is how it must look like in the JSON file:

```
hello how are you\nvery good :)
```

But then I want to replace some elements of a JSON file with this string and I use this to write my file.

```
var test = $('#Textarea_Key').val()


var json_configFile = require('C:/user/default.json', 'utf8')


json_configFile['AppSettings'].appAuth.Key = test  
var gangwithme = JSON.stringify(json_configFile, null, 4)


var options = { flag : 'w' };
fs.writeFile('C:/user/default.json', gangwithme, options, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log( 'Error: ' + err )
  } 
  else {
    console.log( 'SUCCESS' )
  } 
});
```

Everything worked and the file is edited and saved.
But it´s very IMPORTANT for me that \n doesn´t create a new line or will be escaped..
Because in the file it looks like this

```
'hello how are you\\nvery good :)'
```

The problem is that my auth key is now not working anymore because of double backslash. It must look like this in the JSON:

```
'hello how are you\nvery good :)'
```

Is there a way to disable escaping with fs as option value or do you know another way? :)

Comment: Try three backslashes instead. `\\\n`

Comment: The test string will be generated by a form that will set by the user so I need to replace it with the script but this is not working for me
test = test.replace(/[\\]/gmi, '\') can´t be used because of no escaping of '\'
OR
test = test.replace(/[\\]/gmi, '\\') will result again \\n
OR
test = test.replace(/[\\]/gmi, '\\\\') not working will result \\\\
How can I replace it with a regex from string test? Also I think the string test is in default correct only fs.writeFile will escape the \n

Comment: There's no reason to care about the exact escaping used in JSON.

Comment: When my key is '123\n456' the auth process is working.
but when my key is '123\\n456' in the JSON it doesn´t work anymore because the letter n will added to the auth key I think ^^

Comment: Where does your `test` form string exactly come from ? Because a console.log displaying `hello how are you\nvery good :)` means your backslash is already escaped (otherwise you would see two separate lines and no \n). This is an issue with the source string already including two backslashes (one escaping the other), not the `fs` or JSON encoding.

Comment: Ah sounds right! It comes from a input from here   var test = $('#Textarea_Key').val()

Comment: I edit the post related to this comments!

Comment: So in your textarea you basically need to type `hello how are you`, then press enter, then type `very good :)` for your string / json to include it as a "pure" linebreak. If you want to proceed otherwise and directly type `hello how are you\nvery good :)` and still have it written that way in your JSON, you need to transform the form-extracted string before saving: `test = test.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')`.

Comment: Yes this was right and so easy!! Thank you!! You can post it as awnser and I will set the post as done!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given by @Crogo thank you!

So in your textarea you basically need to type

```
 hello how are you
```

then press enter, then type

```
very good :)
```

for your string / json to include it as a "pure" linebreak. If you want to proceed otherwise and directly type

```
hello how are you\nvery good :)
```

and still have it written that way in your JSON, you need to transform the form-extracted string before saving:

```
test = test.replace(/\\n/gm, '\n')
```